# Given a Wallet Address, How do you get the ERC token it holds programatically?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Given a Ethereum wallet address, how can one find all the ERC token it holds. Specifically the token name and balance. Is it possible to do this programatically ie. by writing any code ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, because Parity and Etherscan both do it. I don't know _how_ they do it, but you could read Parity's code or experiment with Etherscan's API and post your own answer.

Comment: Do you have the list of tokens that you want to know about, or is your goal *all* tokens?

Comment: Will be compiling a list of tokens with their contract address.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Javascript [Metamask has a package](https://github.com/danfinlay/human-standard-token-abi) for retrieving the token info of any token address.

Comment: Thanks for the lead.

Comment: @SyedAfzal no problem bro.